# on node, q.ninvoke is not working correctly in my CI environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, q, circleci

I'm using Q.ninvoke to execute a mongoose query, something like:

```
var cursor = Tab.find();
// ...
cursor.sort({'someField': -1})
// ...
cursor.skip(page).limit(size)
// ...
return Q.ninvoke(cursor, 'exec');
```

This works perfectly when I test it locally but when I execute on my CI (CircleCI) I got the error

```
Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"
```

at the moment I fixed it by changing my code this way

```
return cursor.exec();
```

But I still can't understand why it's not behaving correctly on CI. Any idea?

---

EDIT
this is the stacktrace:

```
"stack":"TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined\
    at Promise.post (/home/ubuntu/projName/node_modules/q/q.js:1074:36)\
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ubuntu/projName/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)\
    at /home/ubuntu/projName/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44\
    at flush (/home/ubuntu/projName/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)\
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)","arguments":["apply",null],"type":"non_object_property_call","message":"Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"}
```

Comment: Is there a call stack trace for the error?

Comment: Could you please contact us via the in-app help dialog or by email to sayhi(at)circleci(dot)com so that we take a look at this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @appplemac sure. I actually did not think it was a CircleCI problem

Comment: @appplemac: If you could solve the problem in the support, please post an answer.

Comment: unfortunately we could not fix this problem in the support and for business reasons I've  moved forward using a different system